# My if statement is not being listened to, fires script anyway

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple if statement (and concept) and its not working...

My code:

```
if ( $("body").has('div.cntxt-rr') ) {
    $('.auto-rr').css('display', 'none');
}
```

So i.e. if the body has an element with a class of '.cntxt-rr', I want a div with the class of '.auto-rr' to display:none.

As it stands the result is it is **always** display:none...

Any help would be great,

Thank you,

Comment: `has` does not return a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

When checking for truth values you should use .length. i.e

```
if ( $("body").has('div.cntxt-rr').length ) {
    $('.auto-rr').css('display', 'none');
}
```

$("body").has('div.cntxt-rr') will always evaluate to true because it always returns an object

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation to why it was firing it

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
if($("body").find('div.cntxt-rr').length !== 0){
    $('.auto-rr').css('display', 'none');
}
```